# How to while loop prompt in Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, prompt

I am making a Scissors, Paper, Stone game in javascript. I have created 3 functions. The first getComputerChoice() is to let computer randomly choose between those three. Second is gameNow() where you compare computer choice with user's choice. Lastly game() is where I want to loop it for 5 times according to the game round.

The problem I have is the prompt let user pick the choice once and use it for the next 5 rounds(ex. user choose "rock". It will automatically compare computer choice with the same user's input. I want the user to be able to pick their choice each round, but my while loop doesn't prompt for the next round. It only prompted once.

Here is my code :

```
let userChoice = prompt("Pick one, Paper-Scissors-Rock : ");
let userPick = userChoice.toLowerCase();
const maxRound = 5;
let gameRound = 1;

let getComputerChoice = () =>{
    const choiceArr = ["scissors","paper","rock"];
    let i = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    return choiceArr[i]
}

let gameNow = (playerSelection,computerSelection) =>{
        if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "rock"){
            alert("Tie!")
            gameRound+=1
        } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock"){
            alert("Paper beats Rock, You win!")
            gameRound+=1
        } else if(playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "rock"){
            alert("Scissors lose to Rock, You lose!")
            gameRound+=1
    
        } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors"){
            alert("Rock beats scissors, You win!")
            gameRound+=1
        } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "scissors"){
            alert("Scissors beats Paper, You lose!")
            gameRound+=1
        } else if(playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "scissors"){
            alert("Tie!")
            gameRound+=1
    
        } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper"){
            alert("Paper beats rock, You lose!")
            gameRound+=1
        } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "paper"){
            alert("Tie!")
            gameRound+=1
        } else if(playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper"){
            alert("Paper beats rock, You lose!")
            gameRound+=1
        } else {
            alert("Have you entered the right choice?")
            gameRound+=1
        }
}

let game = () => {
    while(gameRound<=maxRound){
        gameNow(userPick,getComputerChoice())
    }
}

game()
```

Comment: Move `let userChoice = prompt("Pick one, Paper-Scissors-Rock : ");` to the while loop

Comment: It works! Thank you!!!